# How can I maintain page state after navigating away and back again?

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I have created a button that extends the **Read More** section. This works fine.

```
// CODE TO EXTEND READ MORE SECTION
$("#readMoreDiary").on("click", function(){

    $("#diary-content").addClass("showTextThree");
    $("#readMoreDiary").addClass("hide");
    $("#closeDiary").removeClass("hideExitDiary");

    $(".showTextThree").addClass("animated fadeIn");
    $(".showTextThree").one("animationend",function(){

        $(this).removeClass("animated fadeIn");
    });
});
```

While coming back from page2.php to the index page, I would like this **"Read more"** section to remain open. (page2.php will be accessed from the **Read More** section.)

So if somebody is looking in the **Extended Read More** section clicks a link for page2 and then goes back, I want to go back to index page but **with the Read More Section extended**.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: hard to make sense out of what you are asking and which code is being used where

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what you want. Please describe exactly what you want to happen (in an edit to your answer), without referencing anything on your linked site. In general it is not good to use your own site as a reference, since it may or may not live for the lifetime of the posted question.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution, as it seems you need to maintain states.
Use Localstorage, to set a flag when you transition from home to page2, and while transitioning back from page2 to home, unset the flag. 
Check for the flag, and show the "EXTENDED VERSION"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ls = $.localStorage;
    var flag = ls.get("flag_show");

    if( flag != null && flag == true ) {
        $("#diary-content").addClass("showTextThree");
        $("#readMoreDiary").addClass("hide");
        $("#closeDiary").removeClass("hideExitDiary");

        // UNSET THE FLAG IF YOU DON'T NEED TO MAINTAIN STATES
        ls.remove("flag_show");
    }

    $("#readMoreDiary").on("click", function(){
         // your code here
         // SET THE FLAG IN LOCALSTORAGE
         ls.set("flag_show", true);
     });
});


</script>
```

Use jQuery's LocalStorage API from [here](https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API)

Comment: Hello sorry this is probably a stupid question but how do i connect this api to my project? Do i link it in like a stylesheet?   Thanks !